# Recursion calling function with ampersand

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

How should I interpet the code below? The `&arr[1]` threw me of completely. I just started to think that I was getting recursion. Say `n = 7`. Then it will first print out `arr[6]` then `printArray(6, &arr[1])`, `printf ("%d", arr[6-1])`.
And it will repeat as long as `n>0`.

But how does the address of the second element play into this recursion.

```
void printArray(int n, int arr[]){

    if(n>0){
          printf("%d", arr[0]);
          printArray(n-1, &arr[1]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The version you posted will just keep printing the last element each time around, since on each resursive call it (a) decreases the count and (b) adjusts `arr` to point to the next element in the array.

Here's a version that will print the entire array, in order:

```
void printArray(int n, int arr[])
{
    if (n > 0) {
        printf("%d", arr[0]);
        printArray(n-1, &arr[1]);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could recurse first:

```
void printArray(int n, int arr[])
{
    if (n > 0) {
        printArray(n-1, arr);
        printf("%d", arr[n-1]);
    }
}
```

I used the same format specifier that you had in your example, but note that there is no separation between one element and the next with this format.  You might want to add a space or newline to the end.

Comment: I don't really understand the interplay between the arr[0] and the adress of the second element, &arr[1]. What is happening when it calls the function, since printf already is set to arr[0] will it just not keep printing the first element?

Comment: Thats the trick, you send address of second element, and in second call of `printArray` that element ll be first. Because in c, array is pointer to the first.

Comment: Remember, `arr` in the recursive call is different from `arr` in the caller.  In the first version, `&arr[1]` is being passed, which is just `arr+1`.  So from the caller's perspective, the recursive invocation is printing `(arr+1)[0]` which is just `arr[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C are just pointers. `&arr[1]` is the pointer to the second item in the array.